# How to Pivot on more than 2 columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table which I want to pivot on 2 columns

The current table is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAIF2.png)[image]

I want the output to be like this (SQL Server 2012):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use case when

```
 select memberId,FullName,
 max(case when acc_head='Health Saving' then balance end) as health_saving,
 max(case when acc_head='Health Saving' then MonthlyAmt end) as MonthAmt_Hel_saving,
 max(case when acc_head='Education Saving' then balance end) as Education_saving,
 max(case when acc_head='Education Saving' then MonthlyAmt end) as MonthAmt_Ed_saving
    from table 
    group by memberId,FullName
```